# Can google cloud dataflow (apache beam) use ffmpeg to process video or image data

Tags: ffmpeg, google-cloud-dataflow

Can a dataflow process use ffmpeg to process video or images and if so what would a sample workflow look like

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can make sure the necessary binaries (together with their dependencies) are available on workers using the `--filesToStage` [pipeline option](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params) and have a `DoFn` in your pipeline that shells out to that binary in order to do the processing.

Comment: `DoFn` I'm not familiar with the abbreviation or term could you expand on it a bit

Comment: DoFn is one of the main primitives in Dataflow pipelines, which represents a function that takes an input record and produces zero or more output records; it is described in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do ; you may also find it helpful to work through the introductory WordCount examples https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example

Comment: `--filesToStage` is no longer documented at that url